# Selenium Chrome Driver Under Linux

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, google-chrome, selenium

Having a bit of a rough time trying to get a webdriver spawning under Linux.

I'm on CentOS 7.3 I've installed Chrome, Chromium and a host of other python libs. I'm running:

```
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
thechromedriver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/home/skyscraper/chromedriver', chrome_options=chrome_options)
```

The alternative with a different path runs fine under Windows so the problem is definitely in my port to Linux.

I've ran:

```
chmod a+x chromedriver
```

And it runs under root so it should have access to the chromedriver.

If I spawn it through a threadpool with a timeout it hits that timeout every time. Running it normally it eventually throws an error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Skyscrapercomp.py", line 492, in <module>
    thechromedriver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/home/skyscraper/chromedriver', chrome_options=chrome_options)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 69, in __init__
    desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 92, in __init__
    self.start_session(desired_capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 179, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, capabilities)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 236, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 192, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.27.440175 (9bc1d90b8bfa4dd181fbbf769a5eb5e575574320),platform=Linux 3.10.0-514.2.2.el7.x86_64 x86_64)
```

My takeaway here was "Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally" which doesn't give me a lot to go on.

I've used pip to install the latest Selenium and Yum to install Chromium and Chrome. Feeling a bit dead in the water not sure what my next step is so I'd really appreciate a prod in the right direction.

/Updates:

I checked in /usr/bin google-chrome is there which is the default location it wants.

Also tried putting the chromedriver into /usr/bin and not giving it a location:

```
TheBrowser = webdriver.Chrome()
TheBrowser.get("http://www.google.com")
print TheBrowser.page_source.encode('utf-8')
```

But this gives the same error.

Comment: are you trying to run it interactively, or did you setup xvfb?

Comment: Doesn't matter to me as long as Selenium can access it. I'll setup xvfb and try that way.

Comment: That could be an issue: Chrome driver will fail like that if it has no display. So yes, try setting up proper xvfb solution, at least you will eliminate one popular cause of this error.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use logging to find the problem:

```
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
service_log_path = 'chromedriver.log'
service_args = ['--verbose']

thechromedriver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/home/skyscraper/chromedriver', chrome_options=chrome_options, service_args=service_args, service_log_path=service_log_path)
```

In my case there was an error with display (no X11 on my Ubuntu server). This helped me:

```
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
display = Display(visible=0, size=(800, 600))
display.start()  # don't forget to .stop() it at the end of program
```